# Modular Zend Framework with a base of partials

Tags: zend-framework, partials

Currently I'm finding I have to keep duplicating partials for different modules.

I would like to have a case directory for all partials to be accessed.

Does anyone have a good way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excellent thanks :)

However, how do I do this via the controller? I have fancybox and have set up the ajax layout:

```
$this->view->layout()->setLayout('ajax');

$errors = array('You have lost your rights to download this clip, you have downloaded it the maximum amount of times.');

$this->render($this->view->partial('partials/errors.phtml', 'default', array('errors' => $errors)), NULL, true);
```

The pop up window as required but with the following error:

```
Problem: Method "partial" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()
```

I kinda of assumed the $this->view->partial would be the same as using $this->partial inside the view template, but I guess not. Ideas?

SOLVED VIA:

Bootstrap initView, added:

```
$view->addScriptPath('../application/layouts/partials');
```

Moved my partials to that directory. Then in my controller I do:

```
$this->view->layout()->setLayout('ajax');
$this->view->form  = $form;
$this->renderScript('login.phtml');
```

Thanks goes out to #zftalks SmartSsa

Comment: $this->view->getHelper('partial')->partial('comments.phtml');
I also added it to my answer.

Answer (score 8):

```
$this->partial('directoryOfPartials/partial.phtml', $model);
```

I think you can also use $this->partial with three arguments. The second argument is a module name and the third argument becomes the model.

Taken From: 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html

> Example #10 Rendering Partials in
>   Other Modules Sometime a partial will
>   exist in a different module. If you
>   know the name of the module, you can
>   pass it as the second argument to
>   either partial() or partialLoop(),
>   moving the $model argument to third
>   position. For instance, if there's a
>   pager partial you wish to use that's
>   in the 'list' module, you could grab
>   it as follows:
>
> ```
> <?php echo $this->partial('pager.phtml', 'list', $pagerData) ?>
> ```
>
> In this way, you can re-use partials
>   created specifically for other
>   modules. That said, it's likely a
>   better practice to put re-usable
>   partials in shared view script paths.

EDIT - Accessing view partials from within a Controller's Action scope

```
$this->view->getHelper('partial')->partial('comments.phtml');
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great for the view, however I have a query about using it via the controller, will reply in a new post below to be clearer

Comment: what to do in view when you set partial in helper? I mean after that, what you posted after your edit? You set partial to comments.phtml, but what to do with that in view? TIA